# Is it okay for two “sein” to be next to each other?

Tags: sentence-structure

Well here is this sentence I wrote:

> Weil Einkaufszentren eines von wenigen Dingen, die das Leben auf dem Land weniger langweilig machen, sind, sind sie wirklich wichtig.

and I mean:

> Because shopping centers are one of the few things that make life in the countryside less boring, they are really important.

Is the German sentence grammatically correct? How unnatural does it sound to you to have two *sind* next to each other?

Comment: Consider *Ich frage **die, die die** Aufgabe lösen konnten.* That's okay by German style. (First *die* is a demonstrative pronoun, second a relative pronoun and the third an article, in case you wonder.) – German speakers aren't reluctant to speak like this.

Comment: Obwohl auch ist, bin und bist alternative Formen von sind sind, sind sind und seid die einzigen Pluralformen.

Comment: @Janka https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: Wenn hinter Fliegen Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen nach :-)

Comment: It's certainly okay in French...

Comment: @mic das funktioniert auch mit Robben - und wenn man sächsisch spricht und geinen Underschied gennt zwischen harden und weichen Gonsonanden, dann geht's auch mit Griechen

Comment: Das dass, das das das mit einem zusätzlichen s ist, klingt genauso wie das das, das nur mit einem s geschrieben wird.

Comment: Die, die die, die die Dietriche erfunden haben, verurteilen, tun ihnen Unrecht. ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would probably avoid the long subordinate clause within the first subordinate clause, and say

> Weil Einkaufszentren eines von wenigen Dingen sind, die das Leben auf dem Land weniger langweilig machen, sind sie wirklich wichtig.

instead. But grammatically, the original sentence is fine; there's no rule against two successive occurrences of "sind".

Comment: ich würde sagen: "eines der wenigen Dinge sind"

Comment: @Iris Ja, richtig, das wäre idiomatischer.

Answer (score 4):

> *"Weil sie gut erzählt sind, sind Sindbads Reiseabenteuer so beliebt"...*

(Ok, the third "sind" is not really the same, but for the fun of it...;) )

update- deppenapostroph removed...

Comment: @mic - urrrm, urrks.......